# Captcha with merging a number with real image

Tags: image, image-processing, merge, captcha

I have searched for captcha generation tools, but I could not find any tool which can generate the below captcha pictures.

[image: Captcha with image]

You can seen these when you want to register on google. It uses a number merged on a real picture and produce a new real image picture.
Do you know any tools that which can do this ?! By the way, what this is the name of this kind of captcha ( or image merging technique )?

Comment: What makes you think the numbers are merged onto the pictures? I may be wrong, and I have not looked at them very closely, but they look like straightforward photos of things with numbers on them to me...

Comment: @MarkSetchell then google should have large amount of these pictures ! (May be fetch them from google street images )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sources these Captcha images from Street View imagery.  Direct quote from Google spokesperson:

> We’re currently running an experiment in which characters from Street
>   View images are appearing in CAPTCHAs. We often extract data such as
>   street names and traffic signs from Street View imagery to improve
>   Google Maps with useful information like business addresses and
>   locations. Based on the data and results of these reCaptcha tests,
>   we’ll determine if using imagery might also be an effective way to
>   further refine our tools for fighting machine and bot-related abuse
>   online.

source: [techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/29/google-now-using-recaptcha-to-decode-street-view-addresses/)